# Uncaught ReferenceError for SoundCloud SDK

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use the SoundCloud sdk for javascript and I keep getting a "Uncaught ReferenceError: SC is not defined" error.

I followed everything on the reference page https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks right here.

I looked at all the other questions similar to mine on here and people suggested splitting the script tags so one of them has the src attribute and the other one has the actual script.

But I already have done this and it isn't solving my problem.

Here is my code:

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            SC.initialize({
                client_id: "3f7407c6252e6932c8ef6ea85c55e9c7"
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code seems to be working correctly, check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4k31v0ec/.
I've added

```
console.log(SC);
```

to see if the API object is initialised. So maybe you have error in other part of your page code?

**UPD**

try using **https** url for library url:

```
https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk-2.0.0.js
```